# Passing Data Tableview -> Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I have this tableview and I would like to pass the username to a view controller and display it there in a label, but it does not work. The username comes from a firebase database. I also checked other questions but cannot adopt it to my problem. I am not expert in coding:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

struct user {
     let username : String!
}

class MainScreen: UITableViewController {

     var Users = [user]()

     override func viewDidLoad() {

     let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

     databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey()
                .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)
        let username = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["username"] as! String
        print(username)
        self.Users.append(user(username: username))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(self.Users)
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                       numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    let nameLbl = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    nameLbl.text = self.Users[indexPath.row].username
    return cell!
    }

@IBAction func ShowDetail(_ sender: Any) {
    var selectedLabel:String?

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
                    didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row)selected")
        selectedLabel = self.Users[indexPath.row].username
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailView", sender: self)
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! CallDetail
            vc.stringPassed = selectedLabel!
        }
     }
}
```

And the receiving ViewController looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class CallDetail: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!
     var stringPassed = String()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         UserName = stringPassed.text
     }
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of func ShowDetail(_ sender: Any) method? you should implement its inner method on the same class scope level

Comment: Can you tell us what isn't working? For example in your observe closure, does print(snapshot) print the snapshot? Does print(userName) print the user name? Where are you 'passing' the data? It appears it's stored in an array and then assigned to a variable once the viewController in instantiated (which isn't passing the username)

Comment: Hi Jay, sorry for not being precise enough. The only thing, from my perspective, that does not work is the passing of the data. So, the label in the new Viewcontroller stays blank. I am passing the data to an other view controller and there the username should appear in the label field. In essence I try to build a tableview with a detail (detail in Viewcontroller).

Answer (score 1):

Both of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue` methods should be outside  of `@IBAction func ShowDetail(_ sender: Any)` (actually, I can't figure the purpose of it):

declare `selectedLabel` as an instance variable and separate the methods:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

struct user {
    let username : String!
}

class MainScreen: UITableViewController {

    // 'selectedLabel' should be here:
    var selectedLabel:String?

    var Users = [user]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded,    with: {
            snapshot in

            print(snapshot)

            let username        = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["username"] as! String

            print(username)

            self.Users.append(user(username: username))

            self.tableView.reloadData()

            print(self.Users)

        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Users.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        let nameLbl = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        nameLbl.text = self.Users[indexPath.row].username

        return cell!

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row)selected")
        selectedLabel = self.Users[indexPath.row].username
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailView", sender: self)
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! CallDetail

            vc.stringPassed = selectedLabel!
        }
    }

    // just remove it if you don't need it...
    @IBAction func ShowDetail(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

Also, make sure that the tableView data source and delegate are connected to the viewController.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but it still does not work. I have the following error in compiler: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: the error is generated in the DetailViewController: 

    class CallDetail: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!
     var stringPassed:String?
 
    
    

    
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
      UserName.text = stringPassed

Comment: this worked successfully for me when pass data from button in cell to another view controller. How would you get this to work in with sections? like say calling this in the footer cell to pass the label data to another view controller.the results im getting right now are showing the same label data for only one of the sections

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove

`tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath` because it will be called automatically when you click on a cell, if you've set the tableView delegate to the viewController.

`prepareForSegue` will be called after `performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailView", sender: self)` and delete `ShowDetail(_ sender: Any)` it's not necessary.

and change these lines

```
let nameLbl = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

nameLbl.text = self.Users[indexPath.row].username
```

to

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.Users[indexPath.row].username
```